# Parsing javascript from html site

Tags: javascript, android, html, regex, jsoup

I have this as a part of html site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('player_container').setup(
            {                      
                'width': '640',               
                'height': '384',
                'players': [ {type: 'flash', src: '/player/player.swf'} ],
                'file':'http://video.sibnet.ru/v/98a6a9525d30afd623457f445ca95199/1321852.mp4'
                // .....
            });
```

And i want to get that value of 'file' to string, but I don't know how to do that. That code is only part of what I parsed with jsoup (I ordered it to show all ). I tried regex online generator, but it doesn't get it though. Maybe I will just post  what I tried:

```
                            String re1="(\\'.*?\\')";   
                            String re2=".*?";   
                            String re3="(\\'.*?\\')";

                            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
                            Matcher m = p.matcher(sfile);
                            while (m.find())
                            {
                                String strng1=m.group(1);
                                String httpurl1=m.group(2);
                                if(strng1=="'file'")
                                break;
                                }
```

Can anyone possibly show me how to do it right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want value of `file` field then just use this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'file' *: *'([^']*)'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

And grab `matcher.group(1)` for your value.

[Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uG9aF6/1)

Comment: Thanks for solution and link to demo.I'm grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex is incorrect. Use the following one instead:

```
"'file'.*?'(.*?)'"
```

View a [regex demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rR7eE1/2).

Also, this regex prevents the need to check if the first captured group is equal to "`file`", which improves performance.